# Evolutionary Computation select the right combination

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm a noob in this and still trying to completely understand how an evolutionary algorithm works.My question is this: "after all generations I wanted have been created and the cycle is done(stop after an fixed number of generations) how do i select the final combination from the last generation???"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

- Return the fittest individual ever found during the evolution (it may not be still present in the last generation, especially if you are not using elitism)
- Return the fittest individual from the last generation. You do not mutate/cross over individuals from the last generation.

Comment: Thank you :) Just to clarify something, if I select the the fittest from the last generation do i have to run a Tournament selection again or check all the combinations of that population and find the fittest.

Comment: Just select the fittest. There would be no sense running more tournaments or whatever else.